# SwiftUI How to have class viewable from all views

Tags: swift, swiftui, scope, viewmodel, environmentobject

I am fairly new to SwiftUI and I am trying to build an app where you can favorite items in a list. It works in the ContentView but I would like to have the option to favorite and unfavorite an item in its DetailView.

I know that vm is not in the scope but how do I fix it?
Here is some of the code in the views. The file is long so I am just showing the relevant code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var vm = ViewModel()

//NavigationView with a List {

//This is the code I call for showing the icon. The index is the item in the list
Image(systemName: vm.contains(index) ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
.onTapGesture{
vm.toggleFav(item: index)
}
}

struct DetailView: View {
Hstack{
Image(systemName: vm.contains(entry) ? "heart.fill" : "heart") //Error is "Cannot find 'vm' in scope"
}
}
```

Here is the code that that vm is referring to

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

extension ContentView {
    
    final class ViewModel: ObservableObject{
        @Published var items = [Biase]()
        @Published var showingFavs = false
        @Published var savedItems: Set<Int> = [1, 7]
        
        // Filter saved items
        var filteredItems: [Biase]  {
            if showingFavs {
                return items.filter { savedItems.contains($0.id) }
            }
            return items
        }
        
        private var BiasStruct: BiasData = BiasData.allBias
        private var db = Database()
        
        init() {
            self.savedItems = db.load()
            self.items = BiasStruct.biases
        }
        
        func sortFavs(){
            withAnimation() {
                showingFavs.toggle()
            }
        }
        
        func contains(_ item: Biase) -> Bool {
                savedItems.contains(item.id)
            }
        
        // Toggle saved items
        func toggleFav(item: Biase) {
            if contains(item) {
                savedItems.remove(item.id)
            } else {
                savedItems.insert(item.id)
            }
            db.save(items: savedItems)
        }
    }
}
```

This is the list view...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBy1J.png)

Detail view...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03yMD.png)

I tried adding this code under the List(){} in the ContentView `.environmentObject(vm)`
And adding this under the DetailView `@EnvironmentObject var vm = ViewModel()` but it said it couldn't find ViewModel.

Comment: have you tried moving the `class ViewModel: ObservableObject` on its own, outside your `extension ContentView`. Also in your `DetailView` use `@EnvironmentObject var vm: ViewModel`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To put the view model inside the `ContentView` struct is wrong. Delete the enclosing `extension`.

If the view model is supposed to be accessed from everywhere it must be on the top level.

In the `@main` struct create the instance of the view model and inject it into the environment

```
@main
struct MyGreatApp: App {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
        
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(viewModel)
                
        }
    }
}
```

And in any struct you want to use it add

```
@EnvironmentObject var vm : ViewModel
```

without parentheses.